# Validation Through a View Model Graph/Tree

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, prism

My problem requires that I validate various fields across a view model according to some dependencies.  I'm using Silverlight, Prism and MVVM.

As an example (changed from my real world scenario):

[image: Simple class example]

Each ship can have many containers, a container can have many items.

Each one of the classes inherits from `NotificationObject` and calls `RaisePropertyChanged` whenever a property is changed.

My business rules are to to ensure that *Item.Colour*, *Item.Name* and *Item.Size* are not empty when the property *Ship.TypeId* is equal to 1.  If *Ship.TypeId* is equal to anything else, I do not need to validate the properties in *Item*.

At the moment validation is being carried out in the view model in the `OnPropertyChanged` event.

The problem I face is that if I add validation in the *Item* class, then the object has no knowledge of the *Ship.TypeId*.  If I subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` events thrown out by *Item* and *Container*, I can detect property changes from within *Ship* but can only get the property name (relative to the child class, i.e. Name) but no old or new values.

What I want to be able to do is validate the child items whilst knowing that the *Ship.TypeId* is and also be aware of which *Name*, *Colour* or *Size* property has changed and be able to raise an error against the correct field on the UI.

Many thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Are you using IDataErrorInfo ?

Comment: I am using `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, it looks as though the `NotificationObject` class I'm using has a custom `AddError` method that adds errors to a dictionary.

Comment: Why do you need the old values?

Comment: I don't really need the old values, the new value would be just as good.  If I use the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` then I only have access to the `PropertyName` property, which if it contains 'Name' could belong to any of the many items (or future objects with a 'Name' property).  I'm unsure about how I would identify which of my `Item` object instances threw the event.

Comment: You can find the item that changed by casting the sender object of the PropertyChanged event to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, since `Item` does not know anything about a `Ship`, it should not be doing validation that involves Ships. It might be possible to add a property to `Item` that does make it possible to validate locally (eg `CanBeEmpty`), but without knowing more I can't say if that would make sense.

You do not specify what format the editing takes, so it's difficult to comment. If both ships and items can be edited live on the same screen, then the validation be made to fail by editing an item, or editing a ship. In this case I usually defer validation until all edits are committed by clicking OK or whatever. It gets really frustrating editing multiple things when you're forced to keep things valid at all times.

If you can only edit items in isolation from ships, and the extra property on Item itself does not make sense, then I would suggest wrapping your Items in an ItemEditViewModel that does know about ships. This seems reasonable since creating valid item edits requires knowledge of ships, so ViewModels in such an edit screen also need knowledge of ships.

Comment: Thanks.  They are all editable on the same screen.  It's a system I've inherited and the current flavour is to validate in the ViewModel.  Which as we've covered here raises other issues when the `Items` know nothing about `Ships`.  I think I'll go for the *validate on commit* option.